# Extract xml value from HTML using VBA

Tags: html, xml, excel, vba

How to extract html xml using VBA. I want to get "4.2117" value.

```
<ExchangeRatesSeries xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Table>A</Table>
<Currency>euro</Currency>
<Code>EUR</Code>
<Rates>
<Rate>
<No>121/A/NBP/2017</No>
<EffectiveDate>2017-06-26</EffectiveDate>
<Mid>4.2117</Mid>
</Rate>
</Rates>
</ExchangeRatesSeries>
```

link:
http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/a/eur/

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with complex formulas or code you are trying to develop. Start by taking the [2-minute tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also, the link you provided returns only a single line, so you can probably just parse it using text functions `{"table":"A","currency":"euro","code":"EUR","rates":[{"no":"121/A/NBP/2017","effectiveDate":"2017-06-26","mid":4.2117}]}`

Answer (score 0):

I have used xhttp resuest to fetch XML from `https://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/a/eur/` and Displayed result in Output Div.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = result['rates'][0]['mid'];
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/a/eur/", true);
xhttp.send();
```

```html
<div id="output">
  Please Wait
</div>
```

Comment: The OP is looking for VBA code.  What you have posted is not.